# Arrange horizontal DF entries according to another DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, unique

My DataFrame 1 looks like this:

```
ID   group_1     area_1     group_2     area_2     group_3    area_3
        
1    basketball  250        scoccer     500        swimming   100
2    volleyball  100        np.nan      np.nan     np.nan     np.nan
3    football    10         basketball  1000       np.nan     np.nan
```

I have another DF2 looking like this

```
ID   group_1     area_1    group_2     area_2  group_3    area_3  group_4   area_4
        
1    scoccer     500       basketball  50      basketball 200     swimming  100
2    volleyball  np.nan    np.nan      np.nan  np.nan     np.nan  np.nan    np.nan
3    basketball  1000      basketball  np.nan  football   10      np.nan    np.nan
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
ID   group_1     area_1     group_2     area_2     group_3    area_3
        
1    scoccer     500        basketball  250        swimming   100
2    volleyball  100        np.nan      np.nan     np.nan     np.nan
3    basketball  1000       football    10         np.nan     np.nan
```

I'd like to arrange DF1 with the structure from DF2, meaning that as a first step I need to identify the unique horizontal expressions in DF2 (scoccer, basketball, swimming) where the arrangement is important. And then sort DF1 with this arrangement (but keeping the right value from area_x).

EDIT:
With the answer of @kait, final_df looks like this:

```
ID group_1    area_1  group_2  group_3    area_3  group_4 group_5   area_5  group_6  
        
1  scoccer    500     500      basketball 250     250     swimming  100     100
2  volleyball 100     100      np.nan     np.nan  np.nan  np.nan    np.nan  np.nan
3  basketball 1000    1000     football   10      10      np.nan    np.nan  np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

First, reshape df1

```
new_rows = []
for k, v in df.iterrows():
    for group in range(1,4):
        new_rows.append([v['ID'], v[f'group_{group}'], v[f'area_{group}']])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=['ID', 'group', 'area']).dropna()

display(new_df)
   ID       group  area
0   1  basketball   250
1   1     scoccer   500
2   1    swimming   100
3   2  volleyball   100
6   3    football    10
7   3  basketball  1000
```

Next, parse df2:

```
parsed_rows = []
def parse_df2(row):
    x = {}
    x['ID'] = row['ID']
    groups = [v for k, v in row.items() if 'group' in k or k == 'ID']
    deduped = [groups[i]
               for i
               in range(len(groups))
               if (i == 0)
               or groups[i] != groups[i - 1]]
    print(deduped)
    for k, v in enumerate(deduped):
        if k == 0 or pd.isna(v):
            continue
        x[f'group_{k}'] = v
        mask = new_df.ID == row['ID']
        mask &= new_df.group == v
        if new_df[mask].empty:
            continue
        x[f'area_{k}'] = new_df[mask]['area'].iloc[0]

    parsed_rows.append(x)
df2.apply(lambda x: parse_df2(x), axis=1)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)

display(final_df)
 ID     group_1  area_1     group_2  area_2   group_3  area_3
  1     scoccer     500  basketball   250.0  swimming   100.0
  2  volleyball     100         NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
  3  basketball    1000    football    10.0       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, reshaping df1 works, but for parsing df2 with the function I get: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. Some ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full error? it will be helpful to see what line of code is causing it to fail

Comment: I edited my initial post, because the comment was too long...

Comment: In df2, for column group_4, what are the values under swimming? I see that the other null values as stored as np.nan

Comment: np.nan as well. The datatypes in DF2 are strings, floats and NaNs (float again i guess). In DF2 there are groups (e.g. group_10) with an expression in group, but no value in area. (e.g. group_10: volleyball, area_10: np.nan). Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Yes, that would cause a problem. What do you want to do with the groups that do not have an `area` value? Can you update your sample data to include all combinations (i.e. `group: not null, value: not null`; `group: not null, value: null`; `group: null, value:null`, etc)

Comment: I edited the question. With the help of this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717796/add-unique-groups-to-df-for-each-row-including-sum-from-other-columns) I created DF1. The problem is that this solution changed the arrangement... I need to arrange DF1 in alignment with DF2 (regarding the expressions in group_x)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217392/discussion-between-kait-and-aukru).

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow for `area` columns in df2